# What happened to HTML 5 web databases?

Tags: html, web-sql

I checked out the site at http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/ and I saw a huge banner there that said

"Beware. This specification is no longer in active maintenance and the Web Applications Working Group does not intend to maintain it further."

What's that supposed to mean? I was thinking of implementing something using this feature. But I don't want to implement something in it if its not going to be standardized(eventually).

Do you suggest that I go ahead working on it? If not, is there an alternative that would be standardized? Or is it just another spec that has been scrapped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means exactly what it says: the W3C has dropped the standard and isn't planning to do any further work on it.

You're looking for [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/), which is under active development.

Answer (score 2):

From three paragraphs further on in the document:

> This document was on the W3C Recommendation track but specification work has stopped. The specification reached an impasse: all interested implementors have used the same SQL backend (Sqlite), but we need multiple independent implementations to proceed along a standardisation path.

---

> If not, is there an alternative that would be standardized?

[Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/)

Comment: Until now I thought web storage and html 5 databases were one and the same thing. This is definitely helpful.